# How to order by case, descending?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to build this query using SQLAlchemy:

```
select * from t order by
case
    when t.x!=0 then t.y
    when t.x==0 then 0
end desc;
```

I tried the following:

```
db.session.query(t).order_by(
    db.func.desc(
        db.func.case([
            (t.x!=0, t.y),
            (t.x==0, 0)
        ]
    )
)
```

But it raised a `ProgrammingError 'You have an error in your SQL syntax'`.  How can I write this case statement in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`case` is not accessed through SQLAlchemy's `func` helper. Instead, import it directly from `sqlalchemy`, or if you're using Flask-SQLAlchemy it's available on `db`.

You can specify an `else` clause rather than a second `when`. You can call `.desc()` on an expression rather than wrapping it with `desc()`. SQLAlchemy 2 has deprecated the `session.query` interface in favor of constructing with `select` then executing.

The query using Flask-SQLAlchemy and SQLAlchemy 2 looks like:

```py
query = db.select(t).order_by(db.case([(t.x != 0, t.y)], else_=0).desc()
result = db.session.execute(query)
```

Or the legacy query interface:

```py
result = db.session.query(t).order_by(db.case([(t.x != 0, t.y)], else_=0).desc()
```

Or if not using Flask-SQLAlchemy:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

query = sa.select(t).order_by(sa.case([(t.x != 0, t.y)], else_=0).desc()
result = session.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `case` function is not `db.func.case`, it is `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case`.